# Handle Android service execution based on events in Activity

Tags: android, sockets, android-service

I'm developing a simple multi-player Android game that communicates with its Game Server using Java Sockets. And to create non-freezing UI, I decided to make `Service` class in Android app to communicate with server over the `Socket` connection. Data exchange is done in JSON format.

Now the thing is, during entire game play, a single Socket connection will persist, and data exchange will be done from-and-to the server, but **based on events happening on game client** running in Android.

Eg; When user taps a button, some data is sent to server and server responds back with some data, until then, client will wait, when data arrives, UI on the activity will be updated, and client will again perform some action, and again that data will sent to server, and so on.

While the client is waiting for data from the server, I'll disable the controls on Activity such that user doesn't perform any actions until data arrives from server, and I'll also show waiting dialog on Activity to let user know that app is not frozen and is waiting.

Now, as Android service primarily works with `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onDestroy()` methods, I believe it executes something in background without any user intervention. So in case of my app where I need some input from user (or wait until user provides it) to send it to server, how I'll be using `Service` class in this case? Also, is there any other option I have apart from using service in such a scenario.

Also, note that I have two activities in my app which will be communicating with the server using **single Socket connection**.

Comment: you need a background thread that receives the data from the server, not necessarily a service.

Comment: @Ran: But in that way how I'd be accessing Views of Activity from a separate thread?